# In Ruby, s = "foo", and s is a String class object, but s has no instance variables?

Tags: ruby

If using Ruby 1.9.2,

```
s = "foo"
s.class                # => String
s.instance_variables   # => []
```

so `s` is a `String` class object, and since it belongs to a class that implements the concept of a string, which is consecutive characters, so there should be instance variables for the String class object to store those info, so how come `instance_variables` returns an empty array?  Is it because (1) what is it supposed to return?  It can't return some instance variable which is in turn a String object.  (2) Is it the "magic" moment, that there are instance variables, but it is internal to Ruby... and it happens under the hood and can consider it "happening by magic"... suppose I have a class that contains the translation of a phrase in 3 different languages, then there is `@french, @spanish, @latin`, and these happen at the "non-magic" level, and the instance variables will show for `instance_variables`.

Is there a way to print out the internal instance variables of the `String` class though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` is a fundamental type in Ruby. As you said, it doesn't make sense for Ruby to expose the internal implementation since here is no way for Ruby to present the data to you except as another `String`.

The same applies to the other fundamental types:

```
> 3.instance_variables
=> []
```

There is no means or reason to expose the internal implementation to you.